# UPDATE SELECT-ом из двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO `table` 
VAlUES (val1, val2,...valN) 
SELECT val1, val2,...,valN 
FROM `table` 
WHERE id=$id
```

Известно, что такой запрос скопирует строку $id в таблице в саму таблицу.
Если, скажем `val1`, находиться в другой таблице как будет выглядеть запрос?

```
INSERT INTO `table` t
VAlUES (val1, val2,...valN) 
SELECT 
(SELECT val1 FROM `table1` t1 WHERE t1.id=t.nid)
, val2,...,valN 
FROM `table` t
WHERE id=$id
```

Так проканает? Дело в том что `val1` находиться в другой таблице, и его id записывается в основную таблицу в поле `nid`.

И как быть с UPDATE-ом, если копия строки уже существует, но надо обновить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И как быть с UPDATE-ом, если копия строки уже существует, но надо обновить.

по идее надо индекс уникальный сделать по полям, повторения которых не надо, а потом

```
INSERT INTO `table` (a,b,c,d) VALUES (q,w,e,r) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `a` = `a`+1
```

а насчет первой части вопроса - вроде проканает, главна, чтоб кол-во столбцов во вложенном запросе совпадало с кол-вом столбцов вставляемых. Синтаксис:

```
INSERT INTO tblTemp2 (fldID) SELECT tblTemp1.fldOrder_ID 
    FROM tblTemp1
    WHERE tblTemp1.fldOrder_ID > 100;
```

Comment: К сожалению, поля нельзя делать уникальными. 

Если так:

UPDATE `table` t SET val1=(SELECT val1 FROM `table1` t1 WHERE t1.id=t.nid) WHERE t.id=$id

Не изврат ли? Если, конечно, вообще будет работать)))

Comment: не забудьте - вложенный запрос должен вернуть ОДНО значение

Comment: да, конечно...

Answer (score 1):

1 - Вкурите синтаксис [Insert On Duplicate Key Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

2 - Старайтесь никогда не использовать подзапросы в mysql. Если это возможно, конечно. Mysql тупой и не умеет их оптимизировать, делайте через join.

Comment: Что "делайте через JOIN"?

Comment: Наверное это имели ввиду?

    INSERT INTO `table` t
    VAlUES (val1, val2,...valN) 
       SELECT t1.val1, t.val2,...,t.valN 
       FROM `table` t
       LEFT JOIN `table` t1 ON t1.id=t.nid
       WHERE id=$id

Comment: именно это. Каждый раз когда ты пишешь join вместо подзапроса получаешь +1 к карме и +1000% к скорости выполнения :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO T(...)
SELECT * FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.AA = B.AA
INNER JOIN C ON C.DD = B.DD
LEFT OUTER JOIN ....
```

В общем, SELECT может быть как угодно сложный, важно только, чтобы количество столбцов соответствовало количеству перечисленных заголовке INSER и их типы были приводимыми к типам целевых столбцов. Кстати, на всякий случай - желательно указывать СУБД.

Comment: Нормальный запрос, и работать будет. Часто это единственный способ. Только требование - что бы всегда возвращалась одна и только одна строка.

    UPDATE table t SET val1=(SELECT val1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id=t.nid) WHERE t.id=$id

Comment: об чем бишь я и говорил :))