# Update с условием сохранить часть данных в конкретной ячейке, как правильно оформить?

Tags: php, mysql, update, insert

Помогите правильно оформить следующий запрос:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO mipsvuser(name,dates) // дата либо в формате "14.02.2008", 
                                                // либо "14.02.2008_15.02.2008"
 VALUES ('$usnum','$dates')"); // здесь будет просто дата 16.02.2008
```

**Мне необходимо, чтобы добавлялась новая дата из переменной без удаления старой.** То есть новая запись в ячейку записывалась со знаком "_", как это показано в комментариях выше.

Comment: а тип столбца `dates` такое допускает?

Comment: [Здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/25518/5079) сам пример запроса можно посмотреть

Comment: @alexander barakin Позволяет, вроде как. поставил тип "text".

Comment: @AzatKhanov, а откуда берётся **старая** дата при вставке **новой** строки? может быть, вы перепутали операторы *insert* и *update*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите только дополнять поле dates и не более, попробуйте такой запрос

```
UPDATE `mipsvuser` SET `dates` = CONCAT(`dates`, '_', 'Ваша дата');
```